# Handling puzzles direct from video games

Tags: discussion

How do we handle puzzles that come direct from video games when the question may overlap with a question asked on the [Gaming SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions) site or should be asked there?

Answer (score 2):

Whether a question is on-topic on another site is irrelevant. All SE sites have some overlap with other sites.

As far as puzzles from video games, I think we should allow them. It doesn't really matter where a puzzle comes from as long as it's otherwise on-topic and interesting.